# How to hide total share count in Sharrre Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery [Sharrre plugin](http://sharrre.com/) to display total

I'm trying to hide the counter from showing if the count is less than (say 100 total shares). This is my demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LittleLebowski/b7vv9/3/)

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo1" data-url="http://sharrre.com/" data-text="Make your sharing widget with Sharrre (jQuery Plugin)" data-title="share"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#demo1').sharrre({
    share: {
    googlePlus: true,
    facebook: true,
    twitter: true
  },
  hide: function(api, options){
    var count = $(api.element).find('.count').val();
      if(count < 100 ) {
          $(api.element).find('.count').hide();
      }
  },
  enableHover: false
});
```

It has two problems:

1. If the count is > 100, the count appears but when you hover your mouse over it, it disappears.
2. If the count is < 100, the count still appears.

Can someone guide me. I'm stuck.

Comment: Did you want that to hide that on page load?

Answer (score 0):

The counting you are doing is incorrect. The way the API specifies is that you have to do it through the options. Also I think you wanted to do that on load so I changed the event to render. Hope that helps!

```
  render: function(api, options){
    var count = options.count.facebook + options.count.googlePlus + options.count.twitter;
      if(count < 100 ) {
          $(api.element).find('.count').hide();

      }
```

So take a look at this updated fiddle and you will understand.

http://jsfiddle.net/P5f67/

Comment: The count still appears for a fraction of a second and then goes invisible. What's causing that?

Comment: @LittleLebowski I believe this is because the function is executed after the object is rendered. So it will render first then execute the code. You can do this opposite and have it hidden with your css and if the count is over a certain amount you could then show the amount. Once again it would be after render though.